# parsing xml in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I want to parse text from a xml file.Consider that I have a some lines in a file.xml

```
<s id="1792387-2">Castro Verde is situated in the Baixo Alentejo Subregion within a territory known locally as the Campo Branco (English: White Plains).</s>
```

How can I extract the following text from the above line:

```
Castro Verde is situated in the Baixo Alentejo Subregion within a territory known locally as the Campo Branco (English: White Plains).
```

And after making some changes with the text, I want to get return the change text with the same tag as like below.

```
<s id="1792387-2"> Changed Text </s>
```

Any suggestion please.Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you want to parse the text, the XML or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LXML](http://lxml.de) makes this particularly easy.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> text = '''<s id="1792387-2">Castro Verde is situated in the Baixo Alentejo Subregion within a territory known locally as the Campo Branco (English: White Plains).</s>'''
>>> def edit(s):
...     return 'Changed Text'
... 
>>> t = etree.fromstring(text)
>>> t.text = edit(t.text)
>>> etree.tostring(t)
'<s id="1792387-2">Changed Text</s>'
```

Comment: getting Traceback `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.ImportError: No module named lxml`

Comment: @Blue Ice: LXML is not a Python built-in module, you have to install it separately. http://lxml.de

Comment: If you'd like to just use the standard library (python 2.5+) you can use the ElementTree module (see my answer).

Comment: But, I am working in server & for the momentum not possible to do it , since no administration access.Any other alternatives please!

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple stdlib methods for parsing xml… But in general [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is the simplest:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from StringIO import StringIO
doc = ElementTree.parse(StringIO("""<doc><s id="1792387-2">Castro…</s><s id="1792387-3">Other stuff</s></doc>"""))
for elem in doc.findall("s"):
    print "Text:", elem.text
    elem.text = "new text"
    print "New:", ElementTree.dump(elem)
```

And if your XML is coming from a file, you can use:

```
f = open("path/to/foo.xml")
doc = ElementTree.parse(f)
f.close()
… use `doc` …
```

Comment: Could you please have a look the following Traceback `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.ImportError: No module named StringIO`

Comment: What version of Python are you using? (`python --version`)

Comment: Hrm… Is it a custom or restricted installation? Because StringIO should exist. Anyway, you can try loading it from a file (as per the second portion of my answer).

Comment: Just to be sure: is it possible you have multiple versions of Python installed? In Python 3 it is changed to `from StringIO import StringIO`. I have two Pythons on my system (2.6 and 3.2) and get into such a situation from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing XML using the dom package (part of Python) http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xml.dom.minidom.html is my favorite:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
d = xml.dom.minidom.parseString("<s id=\"1792387-2\">Castro Verde is situated in the Baixo Alentejo Subregion within a territory known locally as the Campo Branco (English: White Plains).</s>")
oldText = d.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data
d.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data = "Changed text"
d.toxml()
```

But this does not help you parse the text, so I am not sure what you exactly want there.

Comment: I want to extract the following text from the above line:
    
    `Castro Verde is situated in the Baixo Alentejo Subregion within a territory known locally as the Campo Branco (English: White Plains).`